# scrollview not responding

Tags: android

In one screen in my app, I have one ListFragment that is not responding to gestures.  In other screens, my ListFragments behave appropriately - moving up and down based on touch.  But this instance does not move in response to gestures.  I have tried setting the height to a specific dip, enclosing the ListFragment in a ScrollView but nothing works. Logs prove there are 3 entries in the list but only the first one and half of the second are visible.  I can select the first entry from the list.

The xml follows.  It's the inner fragment identified by " android:name="com.chex.control.LabelList"" that is not scrolling.

Has anyone encountered this problem and solved it?

Thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_interval_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Interval" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/days_in_interval"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="days in interval"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/goodi_goal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="goodi goal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/label_selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/default_label_pane"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Default Labels" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                    <fragment
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/default_labels_fragment"
                        android:name="com.chex.control.LabelList"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:focusable="true" >
                    </fragment>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/add_remove_label_selector"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add_label_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/remove_label_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Remove" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/label_pane"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Inteval Labels" />

                <fragment
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/interval_labels_fragment"
                    android:name="com.chex.control.IntervalLabelList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true" >
                </fragment>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/new_label"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="new label"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/keep_discard_button_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/keep_interval_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Keep" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/discard_interval_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Discard" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

here is the fragment .java

```
package com.chex.control;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.chex.R;
import com.chex.storage.Child;
import com.chex.storage.DatabaseConstants;
import com.chex.storage.DatabaseHelper;
import com.chex.storage.DatabaseIO;
import com.chex.storage.Label;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * presents all the labels on the device.
 */
public class LabelList extends ListFragment implements DatabaseConstants,
        GoodiList {

    private final String TAG = "LabelList";

    ArrayAdapter<Label> adapter = null;

    private ListParent parentActivity;

    private Label[] values;

    private Label currentItem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.e(TAG, "on Create");
        ArrayList<Label> labelList = Label.getLabelsForInterval();

        Log.i(TAG,labelList.size()+" labels");
        // adapter = new IntervalListAdapter(getActivity(), values);

        adapter = new IntervalListAdapter(getActivity(), labelList);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Log.e(TAG, "finished on Create");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        LongClickListener longClickListener = new LongClickListener();

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    }

    /**
     * create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of creating a Curso
     * for the data being displayed.
     */

    /**
     * this used to delete. However, we need it to select usually. Now delete is
     * done by long click.
     */
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // delete child - remove child from list and database
        Object item = l.getItemAtPosition(position);

        currentItem = (Label) item;

        Log.e(TAG,
                "selected " + currentItem.getLabel() + " id: "
                        + currentItem.getId() + " at position " + position);

        parentActivity.listItemSelected(this, position, currentItem.getId());

    }

    /**
     * Forces cursor to requery database and list to be update. Used when a new
     * child is entered in parent activity's EditText field.
     */
    public void notifyDataChanged() {

        Log.e(TAG, "told adapter that data changed");

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onAttach(android.app.Activity)
     */
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        parentActivity = (ListParent) activity;

        parentActivity.setList(this);

    }

    class LongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // delete child - remove child from list and database

            // adapter view. Can always call parent's getItemAtPosition
            final Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            final Label label = (Label) item;

            final String name = label.getLabel();

            Log.e(TAG, "selected " + name + " at position " + position
                    + " now we'll delete them");

            // make sure user wants to delete
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            alert.setTitle("Delete " + name + "?");

            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Label.deleteLabel(name);

                            adapter.remove(label);

                            // update the list
                            notifyDataChanged();

                        }
                    });

            alert.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            // nothing happens - child remains

                        }
                    });

            alert.show();

            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void addListItem(int itemId) {
        Label labelToAdd = Label.lookupLabel(itemId);

        if (labelToAdd == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "didn't find a label for label id " + itemId);

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "adding label: " + labelToAdd.getLabel() + "  "
                    + labelToAdd.getId() + "  id argument: " + itemId);

            // breaks because the adapter is currently strings
            adapter.add(labelToAdd);

            notifyDataChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListItem(int itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeListItem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void highlightListIndex(int index) {
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setItemChecked(index, true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The android is not the best with scrolling views in scrolling views, like in your case.
You have to try to avoid this situation, try to modify the layout to avoid these conflicts.

A pain in the a** method would be to intercept the parent's touch event (add an gesture listener too) and pass the event to the listfragment when the user made the scroll on the listfragment (you have to know the coordinates of the fragment inside the screen, etc). It sounds a lot easier then as is and will cause a lot of issues after that, so i recommend to rewrite your layout instead.